# ERC721 0.7.3 - Check to see if user has a token in another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I'm writing a new contract and want to check to see if the user has a SPECIFIC tokenId in another contract that is already on the block chain.

I was hoping to make use of the "ownerOf" function, but this function is only related to its parent contract. Is there a way I can somehow do something like this:

```
IECR721 externalContract = IERC721(0xAbcDefg.....1234xyz);
function test(uint256 tokenId) public {
   require(externalContract.ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender, "You do not own this token in the other contract");
    // ...do stuff
}
```

Comment: The code seems to be correct, you can call the external functions of any contract.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use an interface that includes among other functions that precise function:

```
interface IERC721 {
    //...(other functions)
    function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) external view returns (address owner);
    //...(other functions)
}
```

You will be able to use its ownerOf function like this:

```
IERC721(externalContractAddress).ownerOf(tokenId);
```

If the function is part of the parent contract, you can possibly use it in the child contract as well. As long as it is inherited, they are used under the same contract address.